# Dealing with sparse data optimally

Tags: python, time-series, data-modeling

I've got climate data from multiple rooms in a building, and a working model that I can use to predict the temperature in one critical room. As the climate sensors report only changes, I have very sparse data. Currently, I solve this by interpolating. For example:

25 sensors, who report on their own, generate about 1000 'events'. The resulting table is therefore 25 * 1000 = 25 000 rows, and three columns (timestamp, sensor, and value).

If I reshape this where every sensor gets its own column, I get a table of 25000 rows and 25 + 1 columns (timestamp, value_sensor_1, value_sensor_2, etc).

This can theoretically lead to a scaling problem; right now I have 25 sensors with about 1000 events per sensor per day, for the past three years. And it's likely the number of sensors and events (due to increased sensitivity) will go up.

I'll likely limit the dataset (in time), so there won't be an actual problem, but the theoretical question remains: is there a method/model/package/way of training a predictive model in Python that can deal with this kind of sparse data that doesn't interpolate everything first?

Comment: Does it not suffice to interpolate the sensor data to a common time base for each sensor individually? Or are spatial (sensor-sensor) correlations important here?

Comment: Interpolation works quite well, but the resulting dataframe gets quite large, with many repetitions/interpolated values, which doesn't really add much. This makes building a model slow and inefficient.

Comment: Well, in the case of non-Euclidean (like irregularly sampled) data, you could consider building a graph model of which the nodes are embedded in a space defined by time and location of the sensor. Training a Graph Neural Network (GNN) with convolutions along the time dimension could work